# Loop executing both if and else

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, loops

Hi I have  two functions 1st one checks a condition if it is true it returns a variable. that variable is used in 2nd functions if statement. Something like this

```js
private MapHeightCollision(feature: any) {
    const mapElementHeight = $(this.gisMapElement).height();
    let spiralcounter = UtilityConst.SPIRAL_COUNTER;
    const height = UtilityConst.INITIAL_BUBBLE_HEIGHT;
    let rotation = 0;
    const plotxy: any = this.markerSpiral(spiralcounter, feature, rotation);
    let delta;

    if (plotxy.y > 0 || (plotxy.y + height) > mapElementHeight) {
        delta = (plotxy.y + height) - mapElementHeight;
        console.log("collide")

    }
    return delta;

    return true;
}


private abc() {
    if (this.MapHeightCollision(feature)) {
        const y = plots.y;
        const delta = this.MapHeightCollision(feature)
        $(markerBubble).css({
            top: y + delta,
            left: plots.x,

        });

    } else {
        $(markerBubble).css({
            top: plots.y,
            left: plots.x,
        });
    }
}
```

What is happening is when i use breakpoint the condition in abc() goes through if adds delta and then straight goes into else condition as well. so the final value is always printed according to else condition.

I want it to print only if conditions value if MapHeightCollision() returns some value.

Comment: Your `return delta;` line looks suspiciously like it should be on the other side of the `}` on that line.  Also, you run the `MapHeightCollision` method twice in `abc`.  If the `MapHeightCollision` method could return a different value the second time, you should consider only calling it once, storing its result to a variable, and then test against that variable the second time instead of calling it again.

Comment: it's impossible for the execution to skip from within the if to within the else - clearly the debugger is confused ... and in other news, unless `delta` is exactly `0`, the `else` can never be executed

Comment: Note also that currently, your `return true;` line in the `MapHeightCollision` method can never be reached.

Comment: hang on ... ***Loop** executing both if and else* - well, there *is no loop* in the code you've shown!

Answer (score 0):

To sum it up you need to change your `MapHeightCollision` function, because 1. you never return a false value and 2. you are using return twice in the same block, so your second return would never be reached.

```
  if (plotxy.y > 0 || (plotxy.y + height) > mapElementHeight) {
      delta = (plotxy.y + height) - mapElementHeight;
      console.log("collide")
      return delta;

  }

  return false;
}
```